# dynamic link with python flask throws error

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm trying to generate a link to a page passing parameters but every time i get the error that says:

> werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint
> 'visualizzaTentativiLinguaScelta' with values ​​['lingua',
> 'livello','matricola','tentativi']

and I can't understand why. I searched for several topics but could not understand my problem. I share the written code hoping that someone will be able to help me.

```
                {%- for attributo in listaEsiti %}
                        <tr>
                            <td class="right">{{ ns.num }} {% set ns.num = ns.num + 1 %} </td>
                            {% if attributo.nome != None %}
                                <td>{{ attributo.matricola }}</td>
                                <td>{{ attributo.lingua }}</td>
                                <td>{{ attributo.livello}}</td>
                                <td>{{ attributo.tentativi }}</td>
                                <td><a href="{{ url_for('visualizzaTentativiLinguaScelta', matricola = attributo.matricola, lingua = attributo.lingua, livello = attributo.livello, tentativi= attributo.tentativi) }}">Visualizza Tentativi</a></td></tr>
                            {%- endif %}
```

python flask code:

```
@app.route('/visualizzaTentativiLinguaScelta/<matricola,lingua,livello>', methods=['GET'])
def visualizzaTentativiLinguaScelta(matricola,lingua,livello):
    """apre una pagina dove vengono restituiti tutti i tentativi effettuati per una determinata lingua"""
            
    listaEsiti= app.model.getEsitiLinguaSelezionata(matricola,lingua,livello)
    return render_template('esitiLinguaELivelloSelezionati.html',login=loginStr(), matricola=matricola, listaEsiti=listaEsiti, categoria=app.categoria)
```

Comment: It looks like you're missing `tentativi` in the function declaration. The `url_for` is passing 4 parameters, but the method only accepts 3.

Comment: thanks for the reply but it doesn't work anyway.

Comment: Having a look at the error message, it doesn't look that the problem is coming from the code that you posted: the error stated that it couldn't find `displayTriesLanguageChoice` but there is never a single reference to this function in your code. The only function you're trying to call in your template is `visualizzaTentativiLinguaScelta`. Can you update your code and post the reference to `displayTriesLanguageChoice` if any?

Comment: @LaurentMeyer yes, my mistake but the problem persists

Comment: Then Mike is right, add a parameter to visualizzaTentativiLinguaScelta (I guess tentativi) and it should do the trick. Another thing: do not use `kwargs` in `url_for` and no `kwargs` in function definition: change the url_for to `url_for('visualizzaTentativiLinguaScelta', attributo.matricola,attributo.lingua,attributo.livello, attributo.tentativi)`